# Creating object with a name given by user input

Tags: c#, object, input

I'm currently learning c#, and i'm trying to make a script that create a bank account and then find it back and add money on it.

This method is used to create a new account :

```
static void CreateNewAccount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for a new account.");
        string bname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Creating a new account for : {0}", bname);
        List<BankAccount> account = new List<BankAccount>() // not sure about it
        {
            new BankAccount { name = bname } // creating a new account
    };

        Console.WriteLine(account.Exists(x => x.name == bname));
        var useraccount = account.Find(x => x.name == bname); // Trying to find the account that i've created earlier
        useraccount.Deposit(100); // trying to add money on it
        useraccount.CheckBalance();
        Console.WriteLine("test");

    }
```

And here is my class :

```
class BankAccount
{
    private double _balance=0;
    public string name;
    public BankAccount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You succesfuly created a new account.");
    }
    public double CheckBalance()
    {
        return _balance;
    }
    public void Deposit(double n)
    {
        _balance += n;
    }
    public void WithDraw(double n)
    {
        _balance -= n;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure at all about how to use List and how to use Find. I writed this because i've it found on a similar script.

Do you know a easy way to make it ? I'm a beginner.

Thanks

Comment: The object is added to the list guys!! This code is correct syntax wise but what you want to do and whats wrong with it?

Comment: You don't need a list to do it so why are you using a list? All you need to do is to create a single object of the class bank account. You can use a for loop instead of a list if you are doing it for many bank accounts. What is your application doing anyway? Why does it need to use lists?

Comment: You need a class Bank which contains a List<BankAccount>().  Or add to the BankAccount class a public static List<BankAccount> accounts = new List<BankAccount>();

Comment: @jdweng ok, i'm going to try this solution, can you explain me how I can create this list inside Bank class and how access it please ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to find a certain object in a list.

```
var query = account.Where(a => a.name == "A NAME" );
```

Then to use this

```
foreach(var account in query.ToList())
{
    //do work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



        }
        static void CreateNewAccount()
        {
            Bank bank = new Bank();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for a new account.");
            string bname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Creating a new account for : {0}", bname);
            BankAccount account = new BankAccount(bname, 0);

            Console.WriteLine(bank.GetAccounts().Exists(x => x.name == bname));
            var useraccount = bank.GetAccount(bname); // Trying to find the account that i've created earlier
            useraccount.Deposit(100); // trying to add money on it
            useraccount.CheckBalance();
            Console.WriteLine("test");

        }
    }
    class Bank
    {
        private List<BankAccount> accounts = new List<BankAccount>();
        public List<BankAccount> GetAccounts()
        {
            return accounts;
        }
        public BankAccount GetAccount(string name)
        {
            return accounts.Where(x => x.name == name).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    class BankAccount
    {
        private double _balance = 0;
        public string name;
        public BankAccount(string name, double balance)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this._balance = balance;
            Console.WriteLine("You succesfuly created a new account.");
        }
        public double CheckBalance()
        {
            return _balance;
        }
        public void Deposit(double n)
        {
            _balance += n;
        }
        public void WithDraw(double n)
        {
            _balance -= n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It look like what i was currently trying to do ! I took your code but I have an System.NullReferenceException at line 26 (the line useraccount.Deposit(100);), i will try to fix it. Thanks again.

Comment: Get account could return a null if the account doesn't exist.  So you must check for null before executing line 26.  You can't deposit money into an account that doesn't exist.

Comment: If i create a account named john (bname = john) and then i'm looking for a account named john (bname = john)
Console.WriteLine(bank.GetAccounts().Exists(x => x.name == bname));
It return false.

Comment: Yes, but you get the exception two lines later.  useraccount is null so you can't deposit the money.  The real issue is you are missing the following : bank.accounts.Add(account);